How to call SOAP Web Service using Spring Boot (parse XMl)?
I have the requirement to call web service [SOAP] from Spring Boot framework as a standalone application.
I have the web service point URL, but only have the xml file which is being send as an input.
Can we convert xml to xsd and then create WSDL out of it. In order to perform these steps, please let me know detailed steps or guide to follow?
I am trying to follow this - https://snehapatil02.medium.com/soap-web-service-client-with-spring-boot-3c7034351c46
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/SOAPProvider/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "SOAPProvider")
    public SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/SOAPProvider.wsdl"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
}

